# Simple testing example of canvas element using Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, html5-canvas, react-three-fiber

I am trying to create a jest test for the example found in this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-basic-demo-forked-297k3?file=/src/App.js

Basically I would like to test the onClick functionality on each box. I have already come across with the fact that jest tests don't run in a real browser. Jest uses jsdom for mocking the necessary parts of the DOM. Consequently I may need canvas support for jsdom, yet I am not quite sure exactly what to do.

*App.js*

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'

function Box(props) {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
  const mesh = useRef()
  // Set up state for the hovered and active state
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false)
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
  useFrame(() => {
    mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01
  })
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={active ? [1.5, 1.5, 1.5] : [1, 1, 1]}
      onClick={(e) => setActive(!active)}
      onPointerOver={(e) => setHover(true)}
      onPointerOut={(e) => setHover(false)}>
      <boxBufferGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
        <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
        <Box position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} />
        <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: A classic Stackoverflow moment where I find the same question as mine but that doesn't have an answer.
Were you able to get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

install

`yarn add --dev jest-canvas-mock`

or

`npm i --save-dev jest-canvas-mock`

and just import *jest-canvas-mock* in your test file

`import 'jest-canvas-mock';`

or

**Solution 2**

If you can`t install the library as common approach.

Try mock canvas in that way

```
window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function () {
    return {
        fillRect() {},
        clearRect() {},
        getImageData(x, y, w, h) {
            return {
                data: new Array(w * h * 4)
            };
        },
        putImageData() {},
        createImageData() { return [] },
        setTransform() {},
        drawImage() {},
        save() {},
        fillText() {},
        restore() {},
        beginPath() {},
        moveTo() {},
        lineTo() {},
        closePath() {},
        stroke() {},
        translate() {},
        scale() {},
        rotate() {},
        arc() {},
        fill() {},
        measureText() {
            return { width: 0 };
        },
        transform() {},
        rect() {},
        clip() {}
    };
}

window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = function () {
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not much of an answer but I found this article useful: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/canvas/.

The suggestion is for proper testing of a `canvas` element one should not be using Jest (or any unit test) but instead, use some sort of e2e testing so that it can actually render the `canvas`.

I was able to get some smaller tests working in jest with the following:

Firstly render your page normally using jest. You can either give your canvas a test-id or (as in my case) put a div around your canvas and give the div a test-id.

I ended up with the following:

```
let canvasContainer = getByTestId("canvas-container");
let canvas = canvasContainer.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
let canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

In either case, your aim is to get the `canvas`' elements context.

From there you can inspect it with `canvasContext.__getDrawCalls()`

This will give you some information on all of the "`drawCalls`" that have been done so far (such as drawing lines or rectangles or what have you).

It takes a little of a bit of inspection into the `__getDrawCalls` but you should find that every call so far is included.

I wrote some funcitons to help me get the exact details I wanted:

```
const getLineInfo = (lineInfo) => {
    if (lineInfo.type !== "stroke") {
        return "not a line";
    }

    let lineInfoDetail = lineInfo.props.path[3];

    return {
        lineStart: {
            x: lineInfoDetail.transform[4],
            y: lineInfoDetail.transform[5],
        },
        lineEnd: {
            x: lineInfoDetail.transform[4] + lineInfoDetail.props.x,
            y: lineInfoDetail.transform[5] + lineInfoDetail.props.y,
        },
    };
};

const getRectInfo = (rectInfo) => {
    if (rectInfo.type !== "fill") {
        return "not a rect";
    }

    let rectInfoDetail = rectInfo.props.path[1];

    return {
        rectStart: {
            x: rectInfoDetail.transform[4],
            y: rectInfoDetail.transform[5],
        },
        rectEnd: {
            x: rectInfoDetail.transform[4] + rectInfoDetail.props.width,
            y: rectInfoDetail.transform[5] + rectInfoDetail.props.height,
        },
    };
};
```

So for example if I know that the second draw is a line I can do the following:

```
    expect(getLineInfo(canvasContext.__getDrawCalls()[1])).toStrictEqual({
        lineStart: { x: 150, y: 250 },
        lineEnd: { x: 150, y: 350 },
    });
```

This is testing that that element is a line with a start point of `{ x: 150, y: 250 }` and an endpoint of `{ x: 150, y: 350 }`

The issue with this though is that **you can't trigger click and drag events of the canvas elements within jest** and therefore using jest to test canvas seems to be very limited.

Edit:
It looks like https://yonatankra.com/how-to-test-html5-canvas-with-jest/ gives another explanation.